# Generate list of unique input values within certain range

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class :

```
public class BlockData 
{
    int unit1; // valid values are [0-259]
    bool unit2;
    int unit3; // valid values are [5-245]
}
```

I want to generate permutation of values over the above fields within the provided range and generate a unique object based on these unique values.

Is there any utility function already in .NET framework to achieve this ?

Comment: https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus

Comment: I don't understand what you're after, besides using two nested for (or foreach) loops.

Comment: I mean, you could accomplish with about 10 lines of code with some loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
var all = from u1 in Enumerable.Range(0, 260)
          from u2 in Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(i => i == 1)
          from u3 in Enumerable.Range(5, 241)
          select new BlockData { unit1 = u1, unit2 = u2, unit3 = u3 };
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0w2WZ

If you just want 100 of them, thanks to LINQ's deferred execution, easy and efficient:

```
List<BlockData> blockList = all.Take(100).ToList();
```

or you want 100 where the `bool unit2` is `true`:

```
List<BlockData> blockList = all.Where(b => b.unit2).Take(100).ToList();
```